# c# replace character by an empty string

Tags: c#

I'm getting a string from a Json :

```
var value = JsonObject["price"]; //value = "1,560";
```

i'm trying to replace the ',' with an empty string :

```
value.Replace(",",string.Empty);
```

but i'm still getting the value with "," that's so strange and i'm stuck at it

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the returned value? You should have `value = value.Replace(",", string.Empty);`

Comment: Yup.  C# Strings are immutable.  The String Class methods cannot modify the initial string.  They can only create and return a new modified version of it.

Answer (score 4):

```
value = value.Replace( ", ", string.Empty);
```

strings in .net are immutable.

Answer (score 3):

Per the documentation for [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

It gives you a new string; it doesn't modify the existing one.  So you need to assign the result to a variable:

```
value = value.Replace(",", string.Empty);
```